# Session timeout not working for CHttpSession in Yii framework

Tags: php, session, yii, yii-components

I am creating an web application in Yii . I was trying to do a sessiontimeout,  if a user is idle for 30 minutes.After that he should login again.. but this is not working. I am using CHttpSession. However if i give CDbHttpSession  instead of CHttpSession this is working fine.

this is my code

```
'user' => array(
        'class' => 'WebUser',
        'loginUrl' => array('site/loginaccount'),
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    ),
            // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
            'session' => array(
       'class'=>'CHttpSession',
        'timeout'=>$params['session_timeout'],
        'autoStart'=>true,
    ),
```

Is there anything else to make this work for CHttpSession ? Due to some reasons i cannot use CDbHttpSession in my web application .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want that the user is sign out automatically after 30 minutes try:

```
'user' => array(
    'class' => 'WebUser',
    'loginUrl' => array('site/loginaccount'),
    'allowAutoLogin' => true,
    'authTimeout' => 1800
),
```

Answer (score 1):

protected/config/main.php : (define the session timeout)

```
$sessionTimeout = 5; // 5 secondes

return array(
        'params'=>array(
          'session_timeout'=> $sessionTimeout,
        );
        'components'=>array(
                'session' => array(
                        'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
                        'timeout' => $sessionTimeout,
                ),
        ),
);
```

protected/views/layout/main.php : (define the refresh)

```
<html>
<head>  
        <?php if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {?>
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['session_timeout'];?>;"/>
        <?php }?>
</head>
<body>
…
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know it works for CDbHttpSession. I am looking for CHttpSession.. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I've read the source code of the CHttpSession. It is a wrap of the PHP Session. So, the mechanism of CHttpSession is the same with the PHP Session.

```
public function setTimeout($value)
{
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',$value);
}
```

the above is the code of timeout setter. it is just the setting of ini settings of the PHP. And according to the [PHP documentation of session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability), after the maxlifetime, the session is just "**potentially cleaned up**", not for sure.

And the probability of it can be set by session.gc_probability. the default value is 1, which means 1%. So, you can set it to 100, make the garbage collection process run every time the script is run.

change your setting to

```
'session' => array(
    'class'=>'CHttpSession',
    'timeout'=>$params['session_timeout'],
    'autoStart'=>true,
    'gCProbability' => 100,
),
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
return array('components'=>array(
      'session'=>array( 
            'timeout' => 1800
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation